# How to get .xap files for apps from the store?

Tags: downloads

I wanted to download the .xap files for some apps on the Windows store. Is there a way to download just the file and not installing It right away on my device?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible anymore to download the app files (xap or the new package format appx) directly from the Microsoft Store homepage.

There are third party sites that offer these files, but I do not recommend using those as you can't be a 100% sure they're not modified.
Also, you'll still need connection to the store when installing these since the device will make sure the certificate is valid and that you have purchased the app if it isn't free.